# Trying to change background color based off if the hour is in the past, current, or future

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the background color based on if the current hour is past, present, or in the future.

Use case: I am building a day planner using moment.js. Every hour has its own field, ie: 8am, 9am, 10am.  If the current time is 10:15am, I want 9am to be gray, 10am to be red, and 11am - 6pm to be green.

I am able to grab the current hour by using `console.log(currentTime)`

I am just trying to figure out how to build the function that changes the class background color. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
//current date and time

$("#currentDay").text(moment().format('ddd, MMM Do'));

//currentTime to determine if the hour matchs for color
var currentTime = moment().format('H');
console.log()

//todo project
// Use window.localStoirage to retrieve and store your data object as string
const LS = JSON.parse(localStorage.scheduler || '{}'); // now an Object

// double click makes calendar content editable

$(".textData").dblclick(function () {
    $(this).addClass('d-none')
    $(this).siblings("input").removeClass("d-none");
});

$(".btn").dblclick(function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log($(this).attr("id"))
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
    var time = id.slice(0,3)
    console.log(time)

    var timeInputId = time + "Input"; 
});

// save makes edit end

// set active time

// make background color of / past hours gray / current hour red / future hours green
var hourPast = hourPast < currentTime;
var hourNow = currentTime;
var hourFuture = hourFuture < currentTime;

// if currentTime > hourNow make background color gray//

var hourNow = currentTime;
console.log(hourNow)
console.log(currentTime)
    function backgroundColorEdit(){
        if (hourNow == currentTime){
            document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundTool").style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        }else if (hourNow < currentTime){
            document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundTool").style.backgroundColor = "#d3d3d3";
        }else 
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundTool").style.backgroundColor = "#90ee90";
        }
}
// if currentTime = hourNow make background color Red //

// if currentTime < hourNow make background color green //
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}

textarea{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.description{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.time-block{
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;;
}

.hour {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
}

.past {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: white;
}

.present {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}

.future {
  background-color: #77dd77;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #06AED5;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn i:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}


.red {
  background-color: red;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
   
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Work Day Scheduler</title>
  </head>
   
  <body>
    <header class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
      <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
      <p id="currentDay" class="lead"></p>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      
      <!-- Timeblocks go here -->
     
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-2 hour'> 9am
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-8 description backgroundTool border-bottom scheduler">
          <span class="textData 9amSpan">text here </span>
          <input id="9amInput " class="d-none border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent am9Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 saveBtn">
          <button type="submit" id="9amButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 am9Button">Save</button>
       </div>
      </div>
    

    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-2 hour'> 10am
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-8 description backgroundTool border-bottom scheduler">
        <span class="textData 10amSpan">text here </span>
        <input id="10amInput" class="d-none border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent am10Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 saveBtn">
        <button type="submit" id="10amButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 am10Button">Save</button>
     </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-2 hour'> 11am
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-8 description backgroundTool border-bottom scheduler">
        <span class="textData 11amSpan">text here </span>
        <input id="11amInput" class="d-none border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent am11Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 saveBtn">
        <button type="submit" id="11amButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 am11Button">Save</button>
     </div>
    </div>





    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-2 hour'> 12pm
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-8 description backgroundTool border-bottom scheduler">
        <span class="textData 12pmSpan">text here </span>
        <input id="12pmInput" class="d-none border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent pm12Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 saveBtn">
        <button type="submit" id="12amButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 pm12Button">Save</button>
     </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-2 hour'> 1pm
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-8 description backgroundTool border-bottom scheduler">
        <span class="textData 1pmSpan">text here </span>
        <input id="1pmInput" class="d-none border-0 form-control textarea bg-transparent pm1Input" type="text" placeholder="Default input">
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 saveBtn">
        <button type="submit" id="1pmButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 pm1Button">Save</button>
     </div>
    </div>




  </div> 
    
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thinking through this, I may need to find a way to convert the time to: 9 10 11 12 13 14 .    13=1pm

Comment: Actually, all I had to do to make it 24 hour format was var currentTime = moment().format('H');

Comment: I am thinking something like this:        // if currentTime > hourNow make background color gray//

// if currentTime = hourNow make background color Red //

// if currentTime < hourNow make background color green //

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea (using a much-simplified version of your markup) that uses 24-hour time to do the comparisons like you were thinking.

Each row gets an `id` indicating which hour it represents, making it easy to compare the corresponding hour to the current hour.

```js
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
let currentHour = parseInt(moment().format('H'));

Array.from(rows).forEach(row => {
  let
    rowIdString = row.id,
    rowHour;
  if (rowIdString) {
    rowHour = parseInt(rowIdString);
  }
  if (rowHour) {
    // Compares row id to current hour and sets color accordingly
    if (currentHour === rowHour) {
      setColor(row, "red");
    } else if ((currentHour < rowHour) && (currentHour > rowHour - 6)) {
      setColor(row, "green");
    } else if ((currentHour > rowHour) && (currentHour < rowHour + 6)) {
      setColor(row, "lightgrey");
    } else {
      setColor(row, "white");
    }
  }
});

function setColor(element, color) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="row" id="9">
    <span> 9am </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id="9amButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="10">
    <span>10am </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id="10amButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="11">
    <span>11am </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id="11amButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="12">
    <span>12pm </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id="12pmButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="13">
    <span> 1pm </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id=" 1pmButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="14">
    <span> 2pm </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id=" 2pmButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="15">
    <span> 3pm </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id=" 3pmButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="16">
    <span> 4pm </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id=" 4pmButton">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="17">
    <span> 5pm </span>
    <span> -- text here -- </span>
    <button id=" 5pmButton">Save</button>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Cat, I don't know why.... but when I insert this code in my code, I am getting an error.  here is my github: https://github.com/grobconnolly/Work-Day-Scheduler

Comment: My code just gives you an example of how to use each row's `id` attribute to store a "rowHour" value in the HTML; and then in the JavaScript, how to select all the row elements, compare each rowHour to the currentHour, and set the row's background color accordingly. Pasting the whole example into your page would probably introduce many errors, but if you update your code using the principles demonstrated in the example code, you should be able to style each row based on the difference between the currentHour and the rowHour. (Let me know if you find some particular line of my code confusing.)